# Is Task.ContinueWith thread safe?

Tags: c#-4.0, thread-safety, task

I have multiple threads that enqueue actions to the same task using `ContinueWith()`
Is it thread safe? Or should I wrap it with some dedicated lock?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is thread safe. It even works when the task has already completed.